# open the local macOS help/user guide window programmatically

Tags: swift, macos

Is there a way to open the macOS user guide/help of a specific topic on the machine itself?

For example I want to link this article from my application to the official Apple help: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp2290/mac

Instead of opening the browser I would like to open the included macOS help window. Why? Because it's offline available, natively in macOS included, translated to the users language and includes useful links.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To display content in the built-in Help window, you need to include a "Help Book" in the app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/user_help_intro/user_assistance_intro.html

Once you've done that, the "Help Book" can contain *anchors*, and you can call [`openHelpAnchor(_:inBook:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nshelpmanager/1500908-openhelpanchor) to open the Help window showing that anchor.

Comment: Is this only possible using the old `NSHelpManager` API? It seems to be quite complicated to create a Help Book and would be in my case a bit overkill.

Comment: Yes, well, what you think is complicated or overkill is not the issue; that's what you do if you want to do what you asked. That's how the Help window works; it displays a Help Book. For example, open the Safari app with Show Package Contents and drill down to _Contents/Resources_. Scroll down down down to _Safari.help_. What is that? It's a Help Book. You asked what you do, that's what you do. It's really not very difficult to make a Help Book; it's really just a kind of web site passed through the help indexer tool. There are also third-party tools that will help you automate the process.

Comment: Note too that because the Help Book contains what amounts to a perfectly normal web site, it is easy to display it online _and_ include it in your app. I've written Help Books that work that way. (In fact, there is also a mechanism for updating the internal Help Book from the network, but I've never used it myself.)

Comment: Is this still supposed to work. I get my helpbook linked and the search is showing my topics but the anchor based show of a page is not working. And i read somewhere that people think it's generally broken on newer MacOS